# How to scroll both ways simultaneously in pageview widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `PageView` for my application. 
`PageView` has a property of `scrollDirection` which sets the scroll either `horizontal` or `vertical`.
code example:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[AppVideoPlayer(), onScreenControls()],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 20);
  }
```

Is there a way where PageView can be set to scroll both ways (horizontal and vertical) at the same time.
If not, then is there any way in which this can be achieved?

Comment: use one PageView with verticle scroll direction which will have list of PageView with scroll direction horizontal,

Answer (score 0):

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[AppVideoPlayer(), onScreenControls()],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 20);
        },
        itemCount: 20);
  }
```

Comment: using this approach it is not possible to scroll horizontally until vertical scroll is ended

Answer (score 0):

You can put PageView() as one of the children of PageView() seems to work for me just fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).